# Magento 2: How to reindex specific ids and in specific indexer using an observer

Tags: magento2, reindex, indexing, index

I know I can programatically trigger the indexer to index a list of product `ids` with the following:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerInterfaceFactory
 */
protected $indexerFactory;


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerInterfaceFactory $indexerFactory,
) {
    $this->indexerFactory = $indexerFactory;

}


public function execute()
{
    $productIds = [1,2,3];
    $indexer = $this->indexerFactory->create()->load('catalog_product_flat');
    $indexer->reindexList($productIds);
}
```

But is there not a cleanest way to do this?

Something like firing and event and passing the ids that need to be reindexed.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use something like**

```
public function reindexByProductsIds($productIds, $indexLists)
    {
        foreach($indexLists as $indexList) {
            $categoryIndexer = $this->indexerRegistry->get($indexList);
            if (!$categoryIndexer->isScheduled()) {
                $categoryIndexer->reindexList(array_unique($productIds));
            }
      }
}
```

where `$indexLists` is an array like `['catalog_product_category', 'catalog_product_attribute']`

Comment: I am already doing something similar, what I am looking for is to do using an observer so I can remove the DI. Thanks for taking the time anyway.